# Powershell - How to list sub folders and if they have been modified in last x days

Tags: powershell, datemodified

I have a number of customer backup chains that are stored on a network share and I would like to create a powershell script that can check if the backup folders have been modified in the last 4 days. This is so I can automate the process of checking if the backups have run or not.

The folder structure is like so: `\\server\backups\customer1\chain1`

The script will need to check each of the "chain" folders for the last modified date and output a list of the folder paths along with a statement so I can recognise if the folder has been updated in the last 4 days or not.

For example:
`\\server\backups\customer1\chain1 Backups out of date` or `\\server\backups\customer1\chain1 Backups working fine`

This is what I've got so far, but the output is the same for all folders regardless of whether the date modified was older than 4 days or not.

```
$backuppaths = get-childitem -path "\\server\backups\customer1\" -Directory | Select-Object FullName

foreach ($path in $backuppaths)
{
  if ($path | Where{$path.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).AddDays(-$4)})
  {
       "$path Backups out of date"  
  }
  else
  {
       "$path Backups working fine"
  } 
}
```

For reference, I used the same script and run it on my music library and this was the output:

```
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\2Pac} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\50 Cent} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Adele} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Akon} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Arctic Monkeys} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Avicii} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Barry White} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Billy Idol} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Black Eyed Peas} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Bob Marley} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Bob Sinclar} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Bon Jovi} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Bruno Mars} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Calvin Harris} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Chase and Status} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Cher} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Coldplay} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Cypress Hill} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Daft Punk} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Disclosure} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Dizzee Rascal} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\DJ Fresh} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Dr. Dre} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Drake} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Duran Duran} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Ed Sheeran} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Elvis Presley} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Eminem} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Example} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Fleetwood Mac} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Frank Sinatra} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Future} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\George Michael} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Gorillaz} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Green Day} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Guns N' Roses} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Ice Cube} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Jack Johnson} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Jake Bugg} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Jamie T} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Jay-Z} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Jefferson Airplane} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\JME} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Kaiser Chiefs} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Kanye West} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Kendrick Lamar} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Lil Yachty} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Limp Bizkit} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Linkin Park} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Lionel Richie & The Commodores} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Madness} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Major Lazer} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Men at Work} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Metallica} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Milky Chance} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Ministry of Sound} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Muse} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\N.W.A} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Neil Diamond} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Nirvana} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Phil Collins} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Red Hot Chilli Peppers} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Rudimental} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Run-D.M.C} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Simple Minds} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Skepta} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Snatch - Original Film Soundtrack} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Snoop Dogg} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Spandau Ballett} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Steely Dan} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\The Hollies} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\The Kooks} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\The Notorious B.I.G} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\The Weekend} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Tyler, the Creator} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Wiley} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Wilkinson} Backups working fine
@{FullName=\\db-server\music\Wiz Khalifa} Backups working fine
```

It is displaying all of the folders in the list but none of them are showing as "out of date". Before running the script I made sure that some of the folders definitely had been modified in the last 4 days.

This is the first time I've ever used powershell so I apologise if I'm missing something blindingly obvious. I've been trying at this for hours and I just can't work it out.

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This line here would cause a problem

```
if ($path | Where{$path.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).AddDays(-$4)})
```

The `-$4` should just be `-4`. Since there's a `$` in there it is looking at an empty variable $4, so it is looking at the current date instead of 4 days earlier like you want.

This will fix your issue, but boxdog's answer has another good suggestion for your end goal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I knew it would be something obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code that with output a collection of objects, one for each directory, with the directory name, LastWriteTime and whether they are up-to-date or not:

```
Get-Childitem -Path "\\server\backups\customer1\" -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {$threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)}{
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            DirectoryName = "$($_.FullName)";
            LastWriteTime = "$($_.LastWriteTime)";
            BackupsAreRecent = "$($_.LastWriteTime -ge $threshold)"
        }
    }
```

You can further process the objects (e.g. sort them by LastWriteTime), or by itself you will get a table like this:

```
DirectoryName                        LastWriteTime       BackupsAreRecent
-------------                        -------------       ----------------
\\server\backups\customer1\Dir1      04/10/2018 13:29:32 True
\\server\backups\customer1\Dir2      01/10/2018 13:29:32 False
```

Comment: overachiever! ha ha, kidding. This is definitely a good way to better handle his situation in terms of formatting a legible output. Good answer. +1

Comment: That does seem like a better way of doing things! Thank you very much for the assistance.